# Add table to dbml in .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I had a application using MVC architecture in .net and had a dbml file. There are three connection strings used in Web config file. The current connection string is for production server, I go to .dbml file and click on properties and change the connectiion to Contentionstring1 for my local system, rebuild it and it throws error.It definitely does not recognize all the methods and all
I am pulling from dbml , but I guess just changing the connection string should work at least as the database is same copy, I built the solution and tried everything but no luck . Please help

Comment: What error does it throw? Runtime exception?

Comment: Whenevr I am changing Connection string to my local connection string, it will not hold in that dbml file property. I created a new one, then tried connection to database, connection failed.I changed the password and saved and it changes to another connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **"yourDBML.designer.cs"** in it you will find the

```
base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CookItHere"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
```

Change it as your required one. hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to be really careful about the autogenerated connection strings in a .dbml. I assume that you're using the wizard to create the dbml? If you've got to the stage where it has created connectionstring1 then you've got some sort of duplicate and it will keep coming back to bite you.

My advice would be to get rid of the dbml, clear out all the connection strings from your web.config file and start again. Work through the dbml generation process one at a time and make sure that you have unique connection strings every time you create a new one.